# JQuery autocomplete problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Im using JQuerys Autocomplete plugin, but it doesn't autocomplete upon entering anything.

Any ideas why it doesnt work? The basic example works, but not mine.

```
var ppl = {"ppl":[{"name":"peterpeter", "work":"student"},
     {"name":"piotr","work":"student"}]};

var options = {
    matchContains: true,  // So we can search inside string too
    minChars: 2,      // this sets autocomplete to begin from X characters
    dataType: 'json', 
    parse: function(data) {
        var parsed = [];
        data = data.ppl;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            parsed[parsed.length] = {
                data: data[i],  // the entire JSON entry
                value: data[i].name,  // the default display value
                result: data[i].name // to populate the input element 
            };
        }
        return parsed;
    },
    // To format the data returned by the autocompleter for display
    formatItem: function(item) { 
        return item.name; 
    }
};

$('#inputplace').autocomplete(ppl, options);
```

Ok. Updated:

```
<input type="text" id="inputplace" />
```

So, when entering for example "peter" in the input field. No autocomplete suggestions appear. It should give "peterpeter" but nothing happens.

And one more thing. Using this example works perfectly.

```
var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$("#inputplace").autocomplete(data);
```

Comment: `var ppljson = eval(ppl);` Why? `ppl` is already a valid JS object. Would have made sense if `ppl` was a string (`'{ ... }'`) and _needed_ to be `eval()`'ed.

Comment: Yes, true that. Removed eval, but it still doesnt work. any idea? :)

Comment: Well what **exactly** does "it doesn't work" mean?  Errors?  Browser crash?  Text comes out backwards?  You're not helping us here.

Comment: Also, what exactly is "inputplace"?

Comment: If youve read the sentence above -- "but it doesn't autocomplete upon entering anything"

Comment: OK - which autocomplete plugin are we talking about?  There are several.

Comment: Yea, should've added which.  
Autocomplete - jQuery plugin 1.0.2
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, looking at the code in that plugin, the "parse" option looks like it's only called when the data is retrieved by an AJAX call. As an experiment, you might try passing in the data such that you don't need it:

```
var ppl = [{"name":"peterpeter", "work":"student"},
 {"name":"piotr","work":"student"}];
```

Comment: Ooooh, thats why. Yes, tried with your version of ppl and took away the parse function and now it works! :DD Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, well that's great!  Of course if you eventually *do* use Ajax callbacks, you can restore your "parse" handler. (I don't think it hurts anything to have it part of the options when you're not doing Ajax, if that would help with testing.)